# Node - Run last bash command

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, node.js

What is happening:

- user starts local react server via any variation of `npm [run] start[:mod]`
- my `prestart` script runs and kills the local webserver if found
- Once `pkill node` is run, that kills the `npm start` script as well so I want to run the starting command again.

My current solution is to do

```
history 1 | awk '/some-regex/
```

to get the name of the last command which I can run with

```
exec('bash -c 'sleep 1 ; pkill node && ${previousCommand}' &')
```

This is starting to get pretty hacky so I'm thinking there has to be a better way to do this.

My node script so far:

```
const execSync = require("child_process").execSync;
const exec = require("child_process").exec;

const netcat = execSync('netcat -z 127.0.0.1 3000; echo $?') == 1 ? true : false; // true when :3000 is available @jkr

if(netcat == false) {
    exec(`bash -c 'sleep 1 ; pkill node' &`);
    console.warn('\x1b[32m%s\x1b[0m', `\nKilling all local webservers, please run 'npm start' again.\n`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

There seems to be an npm package which does this: kill-port

```js
const kill = require('kill-port')

kill(port, 'tcp').then(console.log).catch(console.log)
```

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port

I understand this might not answer the question of running last command but should solve OP's problem.